# Passing multi dimensional array to PHP with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

answers = new Array();

answers[0] = new Array();
answers[0]['question_id'] = 12;
answers[0]['answer_id'] = 32;

answers[1] = new Array();
answers[1]['question_id'] = 55;
answers[1]['answer_id'] = 132;

answers[2] = new Array();
answers[2]['question_id'] = 987;
answers[2]['answer_id'] = 1112;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "collect.php",
    data: {answers: answers},
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend:function(){
        // Do something before sending request to server
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){

        alert('success!');
    }
});
```

});

Now, should this work? According to what I've found when looking for code examples it should. Problem is, I have no idea how I could collect the data in my PHP file. I mean, it's a $_POST[], but then what? How do I collect the $result[0]['question_id'] and all the other data?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Carl C. Carlsson

Comment: Just `var_dump($_POST);` and you will see magic.

Comment: @Glavić Thanks for your quick answer, but this gives me "Notice: Undefined index: answers in..." Not sure why. Any idea? I did: var_dump($_POST['answers'])

Comment: I did not say `var_dump($_POST['answers']);`, I said `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: `new Array()` should probably just be `{}`

Comment: @Glavić I know, but that does not show me any of the answer stuff yo.

Comment: @CarlCarlsson if `var_dump($_POST);` doesnt' show it the other definitely wont.

Comment: Like @KevinB said. Can you test what is returned if you put only `<?php var_dump($_POST);` in your `collect.php` file?

Comment: Look at it this way. All of that data is going to have to be converted by jQuery to `?key=value` format. that kind of format doesn't represent arrays very well, much less associative arrays. there is some support for it, but obviously that isn't working in your case. You'd be better off stringifying your array to a json string and sending the jsonstring, then having php decode it.

Comment: @Glavić Thanks for your help man, {} instead of my array() fixed it.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks a lot, your advice with {} fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never actually populating the arrays inside of the answers array with data, their length is still 0 because you're using string indexes rather than int indexes. What you really want are objects stored in your array.

```
answers[0] = {};
answers[0]['question_id'] = 12;
answers[0]['answer_id'] = 32;
```

Comment: This had me scratching my head for a bit too long... thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the value in php page with `$_POST['answers']`. Then you can loop through that array do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: Thanks, but this for example:
$result = $_POST['answers'][0]['question_id'];
Gives me "Notice: Undefined index answers in..."

Comment: Can you print `$_POST['answers']` and send the output!

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by changing the Javascript to:

```
answers = {};
```

I could then simply access the data in PHP with:

```
$_POST['answers'][1]['answer_id'];
```

for example, or just loop through it.

Thanks for your help, ladies and gentlemen.